# If given a variable, can we take it's derivative without defining a function?

Tags: calculus, functions

Say we have a variable in any kind of system or mechanics problem, we often take its derivative without defining a function that it will be equal to, or giving it a name, is this acceptable to do, or only for the purposes of physics/engineering? For example if I have a variable with no dependence on another variable $x$ I might write its derivative wrt $x$ as $0$.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  Of course it may happen that we know (or at least believe) that, say, $x$ is a function of $t$, we can certainly speak of $\frac {dx}{dt}$ even if we have no functional form for that.  Is that what you were asking about?

Comment: We know that the velocity of a function is $\frac{ds}{dt}$ and acceleration is $\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{d^2s}{dt^2}$. The functions $s$ and $v$ could be anything w.r.t $t$. I find it no offense to mention these while solving numerical.

Answer (score 1):

All variables in physics/engineering are automatically functions of the state-space of the physical system being discussed. If a set of variables are chosen so that

- all distinct states of the system can be distinguished from each other, and
- No smaller set of variables has this property

Then for any valid assignment of values for the variables in that set, we can determine a particular state of the system, and from that state, determine the values of all the other variables. So now we can consider all variables as functions of the variables in this set. This set of variables forms a coordinate system for the state space, and we now can define partial differentiation with respect to those variables.

But recall that the partial derivative depends not only on the coordinate we are differentiating with respect to, but also on the other coordinates we are holding constant. If we switch the other variables out to some other coordinate system, the partial derivative may change, even though we didn't change the variable of differentiation.

Thus in general, you cannot just differentiate one physics variable with respect to another. You have to also specify what other variables you are holding constant while performing the differentiation.

If you have a state space describable by only a single coordinate (the path of some system through time is such a state space - the states are points in time), then differentiation is immediately defined as soon as you choose the variable. But when multiple coordinates are needed, you need to specify a full coordinate system before differentiation can be performed.